# My Request URL points to my ReactJS server instead of NodeJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql

So I'm trying to set my img src as well as my audio src in my React App to the path of my image and my audio file from my Node JS server which is for example: `public/1582834809878-71188186_249463072641040_8764351972645011456_n.jpg` & `public/1582834809881-A_Typical_Ride_Out.mp3`. I set my proxy to `"proxy": "http://localhost:3000"` in the package.json of my React App which is what the server runs on in my Node JS app. For some reason when I click on Media or Image in my Network tab in Developer Tools and read the Header, the Request URL points to `http://localhost:3001/` or my React App. How can I make it so that it points to my NodeJS server.

Comment: Can you post the code that these links you are clicking are made of? If you're using an `<a>` tag, and your `href` is like this: `<a href="/public/1.jpg">Click Me</a>` then that is why it's trying to go to the same location as your React app.

Comment: All I have is my src of my audio set to the path and it's giving me a GET error in my console for `http://localhost:3001/page/id/audiopath` saying 404 (Not found) and if I add `http://localhost:3000/` in front of the path it gets rid of the error and plays the sound

Comment: Yes, exactly - when you jsut specify a path ie: `/page/id/audiopath` then it assumes you are pointing to the same host/domain/website that is in the browser... thats why it goes to localhost:3001... how on earth is it supposed to know where your api is at if you don't tell it? using just the path is shorthand for `http://localhost:3001/page/id/audiopath` - thats the exact same thing as just doing `/page/id/audiopath`

Comment: Well I thought that's what the proxy in my script does. How do I specify it to point to my Node server at `http://localhost:3000`?

Comment: By typing the full URL.

Comment: Okay. Thanks @MattOestreich

Comment: no problem @DDavis